# Build a context-free grammar for the language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Build a context-free grammar for the the complementary language of:

> $L=\{ww^{R}\,\,|\,\,w\in\{0,1\}^{*}\}$

I think $L^C$ is the set of all strings that are not palindromes,

but I don't know how to start building the grammar.

**Attempt:**

> S→ A | B
>
> A→ AAA | 0 |  1
>
> B→ 0C1 | 1C0 | 0B0 | 1B1
>
> C→ 00C | 01C | 10C | 11C | ε

Comment: If you consider $w = 0$, then $w\in L^C$ but $w$ is a palindrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word in $L^C$ is either a word of odd length or a word $uv$ with $|u| = |v|$ and $v \neq u^R$:

$$L^C = L_1 \cup L_2$$

with $L_1 = (\Sigma\Sigma)^*\Sigma$ and $L_2 = \{uv\mid |u| = |v| \text{ and }v\neq u^R\}$.

It should be easy for you to find a CFG for $L_1$. As for $L_2$, note that if $u=u_1…u_n$ and $v = v_1…v_n$, then $uv\in L^C$ if and only if there exists $i\in\{1, …, n\}$ such that $u_i = 0$ and $v_{n+1-i} = 1$ (or $1$ and $0$). You should be able to find a CFG for $L_2$ from that.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: can you take a look at my attempt?